# Nearest neighbour - sklearn for latitude and longitude

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, haversine

I have a set of names, longditude and latitude cordinates I am trying to run a nearesat neighbour search on.

```
                            name        lat        long
            0   Veronica Session  11.463798   14.136215
            1      Lynne Donahoo  44.405370  -82.350737
            2      Debbie Hanley  14.928905  -91.344523
            3     Lisandra Earls  68.951464 -138.976699
            4         Sybil Leef  -1.678356   33.959323
```

Currenlty I am am using sklearn.neighbors to run a search on the data but I recive a type error. The data is being stored in a dataframe.

`TypeError: NearestNeighbors.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 positional arguments (and 2 keyword-only arguments) were given`

Additionaly I need the end results to retain the orginal names along with their new cordinate order, somthing which I dont think my current code does. I've been using the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html) but have hit a bit of a wall. Help would be appreciated.

```
coords = list(zip(df['lat'],df['long']))
btree = sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors(coords,algorithm='ball_tree',metric='haversine')
btree.fit(coords)

df['optimised_route']=btree
```

I have a seperate loop for calculating haversine distance manualy which can be brought in if required.

Comment: I think you should not pass `coords` as argument in `NearestNeighbors` when creating `btree`, you do it in the `fit`. It should solve your error at least

Comment: That does solve my error but my outputs appear to just be the equation without any calculations:

,optimised_route
0,"NearestNeighbors(algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')"
1,"NearestNeighbors(algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')"
2,"NearestNeighbors(algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')"
3,"NearestNeighbors(algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')"
4,"NearestNeighbors(algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')"
5,"NearestNeighbors(algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')"
6,"NearestNeighbors(algorithm='ball_tree', metric='haversine')"

Comment: Please avoid code in comments. Instead: edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment pointing out that `coords` should not be passed as an argument to `NearestNeighbors` is correct. Instead, the `lat` and `long` parameters should be passed as columns in the `.fit()` method:

```py
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import pandas as pd

lat_long_file = StringIO("""name,lat,long
Veronica Session,11.463798,14.136215
Lynne Donahoo,44.405370,-82.350737
Debbie Hanley,14.928905,-91.344523
Lisandra Earls,68.951464,-138.976699
Sybil Leef,-1.678356,33.959323
""")

df = pd.read_csv(lat_long_file)

nn = NearestNeighbors(metric="haversine")
nn.fit(df[["lat", "long"]])
```

Now for a new example at `11.5,15.1` we can query the `NearestNeighbors` object for indexes. For example: use it to compute the two-nearest neighbors and look up the resulting indexes `nearest[0]` in the original data frame:

```py
new_example = pd.DataFrame({"lat": [11.5], "long": [15.1]})

nearest = nn.kneighbors(new_example, n_neighbors=2, return_distance=False)

print(df.iloc[nearest[0]])
```

Which shows us that the two closest points are at `11.46,14.13` and `-1.6,33.9`:

```
               name        lat       long
0  Veronica Session  11.463798  14.136215
4        Sybil Leef  -1.678356  33.959323
```

Comment: Thats really good! Helps me a lot. Im now trying to apply this to each row and disregard the preveous row in the answers. Appreciate the help! Please let me know if there is antything I could be doing to iterate this data for each row.

Comment: @Milo Please keep questions focused, and use comments to clarify answers. If you have multiple questions, it's recommended to [ask them separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). If it is something I know about, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, seperate question raised.