# Iterate over a nearest Neighbours search - Sklearn, python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to use `sklearn.neighbors` to run a search on a set of names, longitude and latitude coordinates.

```
                        name        lat        long
        0   Veronica Session  11.463798   14.136215
        1      Lynne Donahoo  44.405370  -82.350737
        2      Debbie Hanley  14.928905  -91.344523
        3     Lisandra Earls  68.951464 -138.976699
        4         Sybil Leef  -1.678356   33.959323
```

Currently the below code reads the first row. Taken from an answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735910/nearest-neighbour-sklearn-for-latitude-and-longitude).

```
nn = NearestNeighbors(metric="haversine")
nn.fit(df[["lat", "long"]])
new_example = pd.DataFrame({"lat": [0], "long": [0]})
nearest = nn.kneighbors(new_example, n_neighbors=3, return_distance=False)
nn_route = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[nearest[0]])
nn_route_pd = pd.DataFrame(nn_route)
```

I would like this to run on each set of coordinates, forming an overall "optimum" route. As well as filter out non unique locations (i.e a nearest neighbor already identified from a previous coordinate).

I have adapted this into a while loop however this does not iterate through the code as desired and is still only running the search on one set of coordinates.

How can I improvise my while loop to apply the NN search to each row and filter out non unique locations?

```
loc= 0
new_example = pd.DataFrame({"lat": [loc], "long": [loc]})

#For loop to cycle through each row and increment by 1
while True:
   if loc < 99:
       for i in df:
           new_example
           nearest = nn.kneighbors(new_example, n_neighbors=2, return_distance=False)
           loc += 1
           nn_route = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[nearest[0]])
           nn_route_pd = pd.DataFrame(nn_route)
   else:
       break
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "*previous locations*?" Do you mean something like: "I have a dataset of people and the locations they have recently been. I would like to filter this frame to only include the unique places where each user has been."

Comment: Question amended for clarity.

Comment: Is this [TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use the NN search as one solution.

Comment: With all due respect, this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). This is only tangentially related to `scikit-learn` or `nearest-neighbor` algorithms, and using those data structures impose overhead that is unlikely to help (as an example, see the complexity times of insertion, deletion, and querying in a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)). Please include all necessary details about the problem you aim to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The question is really asking about a greedy solution to the traveling salesman problem with latitudes and longitudes. A complication is that these locations **may include near-duplicates**, and the solution should try to coalesce these near-duplicates into a single location.

Consider something like this, showing an array of latitudes and longitudes containing one "duplicate" point:

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
import numpy as np
from random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

locations = np.array(
    [
        [11.463798, 14.136215],
        [11.463797, 14.136214],  # <-- similar to previous
        [44.405370, -82.350737],
        [14.928905, -91.344523],
        [68.951464, -138.976699],
        [-1.678356, 33.959323],
    ]
)
```

At a high level: we can do the following:

0. Initialize using a randomly selected location
1. Maintain a *frontier* of remaining locations
2. Greedily choose the next location with minimum distance
3. If the distance between the current location and another location is smaller than some predefined threshold, we will mark it as a "duplicate" for removal. (This threshold approach may require tuning, or may require some prior knowledge. For example: if we were designing a delivery system, locations that are within a few hundred meters of one another may be considered within walking distance, while all others should be approached by car).
4. Return the total distance and the indexes of the route.

And an implementation using euclidean distance could look something like this:

```py
def find_greedy_route(locations, threshold=0.01):

    indexes = list(range(locations.shape[0]))
    route = [indexes.pop(randint(0, len(indexes) - 1))]
    total_distance = 0.0

    while indexes:
        at = locations[route[-1]]
        distance, nearest = np.inf, -1
        duplicates = []

        for i in indexes:
            if (next_distance := euclidean(at, locations[i])) < distance:

                if next_distance <= threshold:
                    duplicates.append(i)
                    continue

                nearest = i
                distance = next_distance

        indexes.remove(nearest)
        route.append(nearest)
        total_distance += distance
        for d in duplicates:
            indexes.remove(d)

    route.append(route[0])
    total_distance += euclidean(locations[route[-1]], locations[route[0]])

    return total_distance, np.asarray(route)
```

The route depends on the starting location, so running this multiple times reveals: (1) the total distance depends on the starting location, (2) our thresholding approach means that all routes will contain either `0` or `1`, but not both.

```py
total_distance, route = find_greedy_route(locations)
```

```
279.87 [3 2 4 1 5 3] # <--- contains 1
221.86 [4 2 3 1 5 4] # <--- contains 1
251.73 [1 5 2 3 4 1] # <--- contains 1
228.58 [5 0 2 3 4 5] # <--- contains 0
```

Plotting the routes may also lend some insight:

```py
plt.plot(locations[route][:, 0], locations[route][:, 1])
plt.scatter(locations[route][:, 0], locations[route][:, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image: 2D scatter plot and line plot showing a greedy traveling salesman route. There are five locations, and the shape formed by the route looks a broom with a handle pointed to the top left and a wide brim at the bottom right.]