# Unique nearest neighbor search on binary data. Approach with KD-Tree failed

Tags: python, search, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I am trying to create a Python script which auto-draws points in a binary 2D image, like this:

[image]

Now assume that I started with point `1`. I will traverse to point `2` or point `n` as the nearest neighbors. I was able to get this with a KDTree and `k=2`.

Now from point `2`, I want to go to point `3`. But the KDTree nearest neighbor search with k=2 at point `2` returns a self-point and `1` again.

Now I am ready to do k=3 during the third point, but it's not what I want, as its not computationally feasible for large value of n.

Can someone please explain on how to tackle such search-based problem? The key criterion being, during the nearest-neighbor search, an already searched element should not occur.

---

NOTE:

- The data is 2D (i.e x and y coordinates)
- Data will contain upwards of 50,000 points.
- **one approach is building a KD-tree again after each search, but as said earlier, its computationally infeasible.**

Comment: There's a pretty simple quadratic algorithm that I've mentioned as an answer. The image you drew looks roughly circular, do you want to connect every point or are you looking for the hull of the points? (e.g. [convex hull algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) may be faster at O(n log n)).

Comment: The "[bitonic tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour)" might also be the phrase you're looking for. You should be able to speed up the algorithm I suggested with dynamic programming.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderL.Hayes, will have a look at "Bitonic tour", thanks. Regarding convex hull, no, I am not looking into that. The image I drew was just an example. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that building a KDTree takes O(N log<sup>2</sup> N) and querying takes O(log N). Building/removing/querying for each of N points should be upper bounded by O(N<sup>2</sup> log<sup>2</sup> N).

A O(N<sup>2</sup>) solution would be better. I previously wrote a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74754692/12439119) that we can adapt here.

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
import numpy as np
from random import randint


def greedy_route_N_squared(locations):
    indexes = list(range(locations.shape[0]))              # All indices
    route = [indexes.pop(randint(0, len(indexes) - 1))]    # Choose a random start point

    while indexes:                                         # -- LOOP --
        at = locations[route[-1]]                          # Current location
        distance, nearest = np.inf, -1
        for i in indexes:                                  # Find nearest point
            if (next_distance := euclidean(at, locations[i])) < distance:
                nearest, distance = i, next_distance
        indexes.remove(nearest)
        route.append(nearest)                              # Update indices and route

    route.append(route[0])                                 # Return to start
    return np.asarray(route)
```

In each step of the `while` loop, we remove one point and search for the "next" point with minimum distance among the remaining points. There's a nested loop, so O(N<sup>2</sup>) is a reasonable upper bound on this function if we assume that all other math/insertion/deletion is constant/linear.

```py
points = np.array([[-0.594,-0.658,-0.526,-0.214,0.230,0.426,0.466,0.362,-0.0580,-0.394], [-0.229,0.0909,0.379,0.547,0.495,0.271,-0.125,-0.465,-0.549,-0.429]]).T

route = greedy_route_N_squared(points)

plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])
plt.plot(points[route][:, 0], points[route][:, 1])
```

[image: Left half: ten dots appear to form a circle. Right half: the same ten dots, but now with lines connecting them to form something like a circle.]

Comment: Hi, understood the approach. Thanks a lot. Sometimes, thinking simple is much more necessary than going into some complex data-structures. Your solution approach is simple and efficient than KD-Tree for my use case.

Comment: Oh nice! 50,000 points is pretty big for a quadratic solution still. I haven't looked through the O(n log^2 n) [paper](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2016/6277/pdf/LIPIcs-ICALP-2016-5.pdf) closely, but it looks promising. This sounds like a fun exercise, let me know if you find anything interesting!

Comment: Hey @Alexander L. Hayes, I am back after around 1 year. Thanks to your suggestion: I made this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSb1HJXRO04 . But 2 big things to note:

1. I used your suggestion but instead of every point, I first converted an image to grid --> and found the closest grid to draw to the current grid. Once found, draw all points available in that grid. 

2. I used numpy to parallelize the entire logic. No where for loop was used, hence the code ran pretty fast. The code: https://github.com/yogendra-yatnalkar/storyboard-ai (draw-whiteboard-animations.py)